# How to convert FreeD packet with negative values

Tags: c++, c++17

I am receiving FreeD packages which has the following structure.

[image]

Once i receive the 29 byte packet this is how i convert X value.

```
float GetPosition(std::vector<std::byte>& data, int offset) const
    {
        return float(int32_t(data[offset + 0]) << 24 | int32_t(data[offset + 1]) << 16 | int32_t(data[offset + 2]) << 8) / 64 / 256;
    }



// This vector contains the packet Data
        std::vector<std::byte> byte
       
        float X = GetPosition( byte , 11)
```

When the value is positive than the conversion is successful but with negative values the conversion shows some different value than which was sent.

How do i read negative values ?

Comment: Why do you divide float? You lose the precision.

Comment: @273K Eventually i want the value as float.

Comment: / 256 must be performed with int.

Comment: You seem to be shifting into the top 24 bits then dividing by 256? Why not just use the bottom bits and skip the division? Might solve your problem too (depending on the exact format of the input data, is it twos complement?)

Comment: @Alan Birtles If you could please show me some sample code how to do it.

Comment: Just take 8 away from your shifts and remove the divide

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried this return float(int32_t( data[offset + 0]) << 16   | int32_t(data[offset + 1]) << 8  | int32_t(data[offset + 2])); , but the conversion is not correct.

Comment: @AlanBirtles additional left shifting 8 and / 256 is done due to conversion from 24 bit signed big ending integers to 32 bit signed integers.